# LicenseException for Xceed DataGrid for WPF

Tags: wpf, xceed-datagrid

I have developed a simple DB-editing app using Xceed's excellent DataGrid for WPF (UX Edition version 3.7), which is now ready for deployment... except that when I run it on a machine other than the development one where it was built, I am getting the runtime exception for invalid licensing.

I have included my license key in the App.xaml.cs exactly [as specified in the Xceed docs](http://doc.xceedsoft.com/products/XceedWpfDataGrid/Licensing.html), like so:

```
public partial class App : System.Windows.Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.Licenser.LicenseKey = "DGF37-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx";
        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
}
```

The correct version of the DataGrid DLLs are being included in the setup and the application's program directory, and there are no other versions on the target machine.

Debugging doesn't show me anything useful other than the LicenseException that is thrown when the code tries to use the DataGrid, with the message that reads "Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.Licenser.LicenseKey property must be set to a valid license key in the code of your application before using this product..."

Any idea what's going wrong here?

Comment: I just noticed that if I put a breakpoint in the OnStartup method and run in debug mode, it never gets to the breakpoint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, poop... figured it out, and it was a stupid mistake. My OnStartup event was misplaced, outside of the app's namespace.